# PHPUnit-generating skeleton test class: error about the parent class

Tags: php, phpunit

I have this class:

```
namespace MyFirm\PlatformBundle\Entity\Destination\Content;

class Event extends Content         //this is line 18
{
     ...
```

I'm trying to generate its skeleton test class through this:

`$ phpunit --skeleton-test "MyFirm\PlatformBundle\Entity\Destination\Content\Event" Event.php`

but I'm getting this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MyFirm\PlatformBundle\Entity\Destination\Content\Content' not found in /home/me/mf/myfirm/src/MyFirm/PlatformBundle/Entity/Destination/Content/Event.php on line 18
```

This is the Content class:

```
namespace MyFirm\PlatformBundle\Entity\Destination\Content;

abstract class Content
{
    ...
```

I didn't have any problem to generate first the skeleton test class for the Content class.

Any idea?

php 5.3/phpunit 3.5

tags: inheritance

Answer (score 3):

As long as you don't make the phpunit command to resolve your classnames to actual files that can be auto-loaded, this won't work because in the moment the file is loaded to create the skeleton, `MyFirm\PlatformBundle\Entity\Destination\Content\Content` is not declared.

Add your projects autoloader to a bootstrap file and build the skeleton files with phpunit having this bootstrap file enabled. Then you won't get this fatal error any longer as PHP is able to find the declaration of `MyFirm\PlatformBundle\Entity\Destination\Content\Content` as well.